# Custom TableCellEditor showing previous entry on add

Tags: java, swing, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor

In the example below I have a `JTable` a `JList` and two `JButton`s (add and remove). In the list are 6 items (Strings) when one clicks the add button a selected value is added to the table.
The Strings in the table are shown by using a custom renderer (a `JPanel` with a button and a label). The button's text and the label's text are changed to the value of the String.
All goes well until the editor makes his entry. The editor makes it possible to click the button so it's necessary.
When one adds a String to the table for the first time it gets displayed correctly, the row's height gets adjusted to the preferred height of the panel and the text is set for the button and the label.
When one removes the entry from the table by clicking the row and then clicking the remove button all goes as expected.
Now here comes the problem: If one adds a (different) String to the table the row height is and the text of the label and button aren't set (because both the renderer and the editor aren't called, I've checked using breakpoints).
Of course I do want the new row to be displayed using the custom renderer, but how do I do this?

```
package test;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.EventObject;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class MainForm
        extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane tableScrollPane;
    private JList list;
    private JScrollPane listScrollPane;
    private JButton add;
    private JButton remove;

    public MainForm()
    {
        tableScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        table = new JTable();
        listScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        list = new JList();
        add = new JButton(new AbstractAction()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                add();
            }
        });
        add.setText("add");
        remove = new JButton(new AbstractAction()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                remove();
            }
        });
        remove.setText("remove");

        setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(getContentPane(), javax.swing.BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        tableScrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        listScrollPane.setViewportView(list);

        add(tableScrollPane);

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.addColumn("test");
        table.setModel(model);

        TableColumn col = table.getColumn("test");
        col.setCellRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer());
        col.setCellEditor(new CustomTableCellEditor());

        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        listModel.addElement("test1");
        listModel.addElement("test2");
        listModel.addElement("test3");
        listModel.addElement("test4");
        listModel.addElement("test5");
        listModel.addElement("test6");
        list.setModel(listModel);

        add(listScrollPane);
        add(add);
        add(remove);
    }

    private void add()
    {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]
                {
                    list.getSelectedValue()
                });
    }

    private void remove()
    {
        int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        model.removeRow(selectedRow);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MainForm().setVisible(true);
    }

    public class CustomTableCellRenderer
            extends customPanel
            implements TableCellRenderer
    {
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                                       Object value,
                                                       boolean isSelected,
                                                       boolean hasFocus, int row,
                                                       int column)
        {
            setText((String) value);
            if (isSelected || hasFocus)
            {
                setBackground(UIManager.getColor("List.selectionBackground"));
                setForeground(UIManager.getColor("List.selectionForeground"));
            }
            else
            {
                setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Panel.background"));
                setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Panel.foreground"));
            }
            table.setRowHeight(row, (int)getPreferredSize().height);
            return this;
        }
    }

    public class CustomTableCellEditor
            extends customPanel
            implements TableCellEditor
    {
        Object value;

        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                                     boolean isSelected, int row,
                                                     int column)
        {
            this.value = value;
            setText((String) value);
            setBackground(UIManager.getColor("List.selectionBackground"));
            setForeground(UIManager.getColor("List.selectionForeground"));
            table.setRowHeight(row, (int)getPreferredSize().height);
            return this;
        }

        public Object getCellEditorValue()
        {
            return value;
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean stopCellEditing()
        {
            setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Panel.background"));
            setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Panel.foreground"));
            return true;
        }

        public void cancelCellEditing()
        {
        }

        public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l)
        {
        }

        public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l)
        {
        }
    }

    public class customPanel
            extends JPanel
    {
        private JLabel label;
        private JButton button;

        public customPanel()
        {
            label = new JLabel();
            button = new JButton();
            add(label);
            add(button);
        }

        public void setText(String text)
        {
            label.setText(text);
            button.setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your custom editor implementation is _invalid_ (which may or may not be the problem) - by contract, it _must_ notify its listeners when editing is terminated for internal reasons. Your's can't comply to that contract trivially ...

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them (always!)

Comment: I always use naming conventions, except for testing purposes if it doesn't affect readability. I'll shoot for the missing notifications, makes sense if it works.

Comment: not sticking to conventions _always_ affects readability - so not doing so in code that you are showing to others (from whom you expect help, that is they have to read and understand it, best at a glance) is about the worst place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use:

```
table.setRowHeight(row, (int)getPreferredSize().height);
```

in a renderer. This will cause an infinite loop since whenever you change the row height the table will repaint() the row and when the renderer is invoked you will again change the row height....

Get rid of that line of code. Instead you can calculate the row height when you add the row to the table. Add this code to the bottom of your add() method:

```
int row = table.getRowCount() - 1;
Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(table.getCellRenderer(row, 0), row, 0);
int rowHeight = comp.getPreferredSize().height;
table.setRowHeight(row, rowHeight);
```

Update:

The code works fine without the custom editor. So the problem is the editor. Look at the source code of the AbstractCellEditor to see what happens when editing is stopped. It fires an event to notify the table so the editor can be removed. You don't have this code. So I suggest you extend the AbstractCellEditor instead of extending `customPanel` so you can easilty fire the appropriate event.

Also, I believe that clicking on a row will invoke the editor, so you need to remove the editor before you remove the row from the model. See [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) for a couple of ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that, too bad it doesn't fix the problem though.

Comment: @siebz0r, sure it does. I tested the posted code before I replied. Update your SSCCE with the new code.

Comment: @camickr I did and it only fixed setting the height for the new row, but the new row still shows the last selected entry.

Comment: @camickr I have tried to make an appropriate cell editor using the `AbstractCellEditor`. However, when I do this I cannot extend another object. As I use a custom panel in my real code which contains a couple of UI elements and a specific layout I find extending that panel a better solution as I have to create either the editor's events or re-create the container interface. If I could extend the `AbstractCellEditor` I would. ;-)

Comment: @siebz0r, There is no need to extend custom panel. Instead the renderer and editor create an instance of the custom panel.

Comment: @camickr Yeah, I thought of it last night and I'm going for that solution as it seems the cleanest. :-)

Comment: @siebz0r, so then why didn't you reply so I didn't have to waste time suggesting something you've already done? My time is important. And why haven't you accepted the answer?

Comment: @camickr I haven't applied the solution yet, as soon as I got on-line I went here to post a reply. By chance you 'beat me to it'. I cannot be here all the time as I too have obligations elsewhere. Also this could have been prevented if a more clear answer was presented to me in an earlier stage. As this site is for both professional and enthusiastic programmers, you cannot expect that everyone instantly gets what you're suggesting. Excuse me for learning, by falling and standing up again.

Comment: I did give a clear answer.  If you had time to repsond and post that you thought of the answer on your own, then you also had time to accept the answer then. There was no need to wait another day. Gook luck with future questions since you don't appreciate the time I spent helping.

Comment: @camickr As the answer itself didn't contain the part where it says to extend from an AbstractCellEditor and create an instance inside the editor, I didn't find it a concrete answer. If one happens to have the same issue and stumbles upon this question the answer itself won't comply, one has to read the comments on the answer. Keeping this in mind I didn't accept the answer at first. As I am still learning I appreciate all the help I can get, what I don't appreciate is people acting like they're more important then me and calling me a time waster.

Comment: Sorry, but the time we spend anwering questions is more important than yours because we donate our time to everybody in the forum, not just you. Your original comment about "I thought about it last night" implied you didn't bother to reply until the morning. Therefore, myself or any other person following the posting would have assumed you where still looking for an answer and end up spending time clarifying the suggestion. Learn from the suggestions and move on.

Comment: @camickr Maybe this clarifies; The night I thought of it was just before I went to sleep, therefor not really able to turn on the computer and post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the addCellEditorListener(), removeCellEditorListener(), stopCellEditing() and cancelCellEditing() methods works like a charm. An editor needs to be 'disconnected' before removing the selected object.
In one of my tables I have a context menu to modify table entries and before removal I have to call cancelCellEditing() or stopCellEditing() else the table doesn't release the entry or it re-appears like before.